# PHPoAuthUserData installation - missing vendor

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

So I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/Oryzone/PHPoAuthUserData) library but when I go to examples/facebook.php there is no vendor.php file which is included in exampels/bootstrap.php and I can't get it to work. What can I do about it?

Comment: You need to run `composer install` in the root folder of this library. The bootstrap-file includes the main vendor folder (from the root folder). You should probably install this library through composer to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about `vendor/autoload.php`?

How are your installing the library?

The proper way would be to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) like this:

```
composer require oryzone/oauth-user-data
```

This would download the library in the `vendor` subfolder of the current folder and generate the `vendor/autoload.php`. Copy the examples folder to the current folder and try again.

Comment: Well I just cloned the repository. I tried with composer but this is what I get:`[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package oryzone/oauth-user-data at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the packag
  e spelling or your minimum-stability`

Comment: @user3628807 Don't run the above command if you're already cloned the git repo. Either run it in a blank folder or just do a `composer install` if you've already cloned the library.

Comment: Okay, `composer install` worked. Thank you very much! I still fully don't understand how github and composer work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that the package does not have a stable release.